# Matching unique Id's to account numbers used more than once

Tags: excel, vlookup

Account numbers can be used more than once in our system(multiple locations)  I have a list of unique id numbers to assign to account numbers.  The problem is when I use Vlookup once it hits an account number that is used more than once it uses the same unique ID # over and over.

How do I match account numbers and unique id's for accounts with account number used multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to force uniqueness by, for example in your case, concatenating location and account number. I'm afraid your question does not seem to provide sufficient details to show exactly how to do this but an extra column (on the left) of account number & location should be matchable to a table of account number & location with corresponding ID.

[image: SO20180984 example]